# Read values inside mysql column in event

Tags: mysql, events

I'm trying to make an event in MySQL to read the value behind "adc1": and write the value into a new column. This value is within a cell with more information, so just saying WHERE x.y = '1' doesn't work.

I've tried doing this in an event. But when I put more than 1 'REPLACE INTO' in an event it tells me it's wrong MySQL. The manuals I read didn't help me.

Can anyone help?

So this underneath doesn't work. What should it be? (The 'make event' part that has to be above works.)

```
REPLACE INTO results(id, updatetime, type)
SELECT devices.id, devices.lastupdate, '1'
FROM devices, positions
WHERE positions.id = devices.positionid
AND positions.attributes
LIKE '%adc1_:1%';

REPLACE INTO results(id, updatetime, type)
SELECT devices.id, devices.lastupdate, '2'
FROM devices, positions
WHERE positions.id = devices.positionid
AND positions.attributes
LIKE '%adc1_:2%';

REPLACE INTO results(id, updatetime, type)
SELECT devices.id, devices.lastupdate, '3'
FROM devices, positions
WHERE positions.id = devices.positionid
AND positions.attributes
LIKE '%adc1_:3%';

REPLACE INTO results(id, updatetime, type)
SELECT devices.id, devices.lastupdate, 'etc'
FROM devices, positions
WHERE positions.id = devices.positionid
AND positions.attributes
LIKE '%adc1_:etc%';
```

Comment: How do you create your event?

Comment: I got that working with the 
    CREATE EVENT copy_to_results 
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MINUTE
And edit in the phpmyadmin 'event' page. With a script with one 'REPLACE INTO' it works fine. It doesn't work when I add a second

Comment: Search [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) for "delimiter" - that might be the issue.

Comment: Maybe you just need `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: I've been stupid! Answer was in 'BEGIN' and 'END'. Thanks!

Comment: This works with a little amount of rows, but when I have 350 it doesn't. Is there a different way?

Comment: Do you mean 350 rows in the table or 350 REPLACE statements?

Comment: 350x REPLACE. I want to extract the number behind the 'adc1'.

Comment: You can create a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in a loop within the event code. However - i would probably solve the problem in a completely different way. First of all i would store the type in an own column.

Comment: Thanks. Still busy with it and trying to sort out the best way of doing it.